# Why can't I paste into youtube comments on firefox

Tags: firefox, copy-paste, youtube, comments

I don't know when this happened, but today I noticed that I cannot paste text into Youtube comments on Firefox 40.0.3. It still works just fine on Chrome. I tried to use an addon to copy plain text only, but that didn't help, nor have I ever needed it before. Restarting the browser didn't help either.

What I mean is: When I press "paste" either by right clicking or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, nothing happens. I could still type into the comments normally.
I can otherwise paste just fine to anywhere else, just not into Youtube comments...

Is this Google's latest monopoly trick or something, or what is going on?

Any ideas?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1080597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty old question now, but I re-installed windows a while back and when I ran into this problem again, I decided to find a better fix.

Don't touch `about:config`. This way, any other functionality `dom.event.clipboardevents` provides doesn't break.

Instead, install [this userscript by Sergey Rozhenko](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/12433-fix-paste-on-youtube). (Userscripts can be installed with the help of an addon such as Greasemonkey or Violentmonkey.)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             Fix paste on YouTube
// @name           Fix paste on YouTube
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      GrayFace
// @author         Sergey "GrayFace" Rozhenko
// @description    Fixes paste function in comments on YouTube
// @include        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @include        http://www.youtube.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function handler(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}

addEventListener('paste', handler, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

> **NOTE:** The following "fix" has been **known to cause problems on some sites**. Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1015644/53514) for a better solution.

---

Answered on [Tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2780359/paste-youtube-comments-firefox.html) by `pcdude234`:

> I have a fix. go to your address bar and type "about:config" no
>   quotes, and then hit the "i'll be careful, I promise" button, next
>   type "dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled" then double click it, so the
>   value is false. And that should do the trick.

Worked :P

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)

Comment: An anonymous ninja said "IT WORKED FOR ME TOO, on firefox; thanks, Gennaro"

Comment: This fix works in Mozilla SeaMonkey, too. I think this is a deliberate move by Google as of August 2015 in an attempt to reduce repetitive spam posting; Facebook did something similar in late 2014, but it only lasted a few months until it was rescinded, probably due to pressure from users.

Comment: @AndrewP. In Firefox only? Bizarre.