# Firefox doesn't allow to paste into WhatsApp web anymore?

Tags: firefox, web-whatsapp

Since today, with Firefox, I cannot paste text into the text input field of whatsapp.web (the PC version of WhatsApp) anymore.

the version is FF 116.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10, previous versions of FF worked obviously well...

No problem on Chromium-based browser (like Chrome or Brave).

Others reported [this issue](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/discussions/whatsapp-web-cannot-paste-text/td-p/37414).

What is happening here? Is there a Firefox workaround, or will I need to stick to Chrome?

Comment: What OS? What Firefox version? Are you using a clipboard manager?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik no clipboard manager, just Ctrl C+Ctrl V. I've added the FF version and OS

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Here PopOS 22.04, Firefox 116.0, without using clipboard manager. Copy/paste works fine if the text comes from the chat textarea itself.

Comment: Still in FF 105.0.1 (64-bit) but I cannot paste any text from outside of Whatsapp Web.

Comment: The fix is on the way https://webcompat.com/issues/125920

Comment: Here's a link to the github issue that @KWriter linked to on webcompat.com: https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/125920

Comment: It does seem to be Windows-specific (@PabloA) - I'm on XUbuntu 20.04, using FF 116.0.2

Comment: The reference to the git/webcompat issue along with a summary of the conversation in those threads (which have come to resolution, soon to be implemented) should be posted as an answer, not just a comment. @KWriter and mhdadk

Comment: i have same issue on ubuntu 20.04 with firefox.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Update**: Seems to be fixed on WhatsApp 2.23.35.6.

---

It's a bug on WhatsApp, seems to affect all platforms, and [a fix is on the way](https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/125920#issuecomment-1688339791) ([here](https://webcompat.com/issues/125920) on webcompat).

#### Workaround

I found this workaround, using [this old trick](https://superuser.com/a/963948/500826) (also [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1080597); [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/pmh0ah/comment/hcifr6f/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) didn't work): set

`about:config` → `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` to `false`.

[image: screenshot of a Firefox about:config value]

Copy/paste works fine if the text comes from the chat/site itself.

#### Side effects

With `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` turned `false` you can paste texts, but you won't be able to do things like paste in Google Docs or paste images, e.g. here:

[image: screenshot of a Stack Exchange image attachment dialog]

#### Working privacy-oriented alternatives

Meanwhile, we could use [**Brave**](https://brave.com/) instead of Chrome. It's also Chromium-based (if works on Chorme, will work on Brave), [respect your privacy](https://www.privacyguides.org/en/desktop-browsers/#brave), and have a lot of [nice features](https://www.makeuseof.com/reasons-brave-browser-becoming-popular/). If for some reason you don't like Brave, you could try [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium).

Also, maybe it is time to move to [**Telegram**](https://web.telegram.org/) or (even better) [**Signal**](https://www.signal.org/).

Comment: well, that obviously works also for whatsapp input (or any input field I suppose) but it is just a workaround not a solution. It is surely safer to stick to Chrome, isn't it? because of: *Warning! Setting the preference dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled to false in the Firefox Configuration Editor (about:config page) can cause problems pasting on other sites, such as strange glitches with the Facebook comment box or frustrating silent failures.* Anyway thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Yes, it's just a workaround. Hopefully will be fixed soon. 
I would never use Chrome. [Brave](https://www.privacyguides.org/en/desktop-browsers/#brave) always work like Chrome, respect your privacy and have [a lot of other nice features](https://www.makeuseof.com/reasons-brave-browser-becoming-popular/)

Comment: Please add to your answer: *Copy/paste works fine if the text comes from the chat textarea itself*: that is the real workaround without needing to change **about:config**

Comment: Added, but that doesn't even is a workaround. I usually paste text from other places.

Comment: yeah, I got carried away...

Comment: you are correct! this is important feature but now limited to do

Comment: @Vickel using chrome? eww Firefox is much better

Comment: Note: you need to disable the workaround to paste images in WhatsApp web. Only text pasting needs the workaround. The post kind of says so, but not explicitly for WhatsApp web

Comment: nice this fixed my issue

Comment: It is worked for WhatsApp but it broke browser's paste feature.

Answer (score 23):

UPDATE: This issue appears to be resolved (at least for me) on 2023-08-29 (earliest I noticed)

I worked around it with the [ViolentMonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/) (browser extension) script below.

As it is only a workaround, you should disable once resolved. Track it here:

https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/125920

https://webcompat.com/issues/125920

This works great but - as with *all* the other workarounds/answers that circumvent the WhatsApp web code - it cannot properly handle multiple paragraphs with blank lines between them.

Here's what I have for now, until WhatsApp fixes it:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Fix whatsapp firefox paste
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      PlaceboZA
// @author         PlaceboZA
// @description    Fixes paste function on whatsapp for Firefox
// @include        https://web.whatsapp.com/*
// @include        http://web.whatsapp.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function handlePaste(e) {
  var data = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  if ((data || '') !== '') {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}

addEventListener('paste', handlePaste, true);
```

EDIT: Fixed it so that image paste works.
EDIT2: Added information about multiple paragraphs/line breaks in text.

Comment: Thanks! This also works if you paste the code into the browser console. (refresh will remove it)

Comment: Sadly there is one side effect - if you paste multiple paragraphs of text (i.e. multiple newlines between texts) in one paste operation, it will take out the line breaks. In other words, if you paste `Test1 <crlf><crlf>Test2` (obv. replace <crlf> with carriage return), WhatsApp will end up with `Test1Test2`. I suspect the other answer involving changing the options will have the same problem.  (Thanks to Mike Turchinovich for identifying this)

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround, if you are on linux, you can do `sh -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool type "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"'` which makes xdotool to type clipboard selection on the field.

Comment: this is legend 

Comment: Good workaround, it's what I use too, but it won't work if the text has tabs in it.

Comment: If using LInux and X11. For Wayland maybe [ydotool](https://superuser.com/a/1378227/500826)?

Answer (score 7):

Another workaround is to inject the text to be pasted into the HTML document via the DOM inspector inside an element, for example a SPAN element of one of the texts previously typed in the chat, then select it in the rendered page before pasting it.

A little annoying, but avoids using another program or touching the browser configuration.

Comment: I did this by typing some text in the message box, then, using the inspector, edited the text and pasted what I wanted. E.g. I typed `asdf` and then edited: `<span class="selectable-text copyable-text" data-lexical-text="true">asdf</span>`

Comment: @PeterWood, you can do that but if your text add some markdown symbols you should then cut and repast it into the message box to let WhatsApp Web format it (been there, done that :)).

Answer (score 4):

**Update for the below paragraph**: it's fixed now in WhatsApp web.

This should get fixed within next WhatApp release/deploy according to [this](https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/125920#issuecomment-1682993012) dev comment and it's an issue of WhatApp's `DataTransfer` wrapper.

Another workaround for now is to download and  use the [Firefox Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/enterprise/) (ESR) version instead of the regular one  - the bug isn't present in that as it's on `102.14.0` and it started occursing with recent `16.0.3`. Which isn't of course a great solution for e.g. web devs who need more recent versions.

Comment: I'm seeing the bug on `102.14.0esr (64-bit)` on `Windows 10.0.19044`

Comment: Hmm, I'll recheck tomorrow, maybe I had something else on that prevented it.

Answer (score 2):

For workarounds, see the other answers.
For a fix, upgrade:

With the deployment of the latest whatsapp 2.23.35.6
and FF 116.0.3 (64-bit) the bug is now fixed and copy paste from an outside resource works normally again on web.whatsapp.com

- [webcompat](https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/125920) locked
  as resolved and limited conversation to collaborators
- [denschub](https://github.com/denschub) modified the milestones:
  sitewait, fixed